# Como podria Adaptar este codigo C# a Java?

Tags: java, c#, arraylist

Buenas Noches como podria adaptar este codigo a java?

- Este es mi DAOCliente

  ```
  internal void getCliente(clsCliente e_cliente)
      {
          string bd = "Cinestar";
          SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=" + bd + ";Integrated Security=True");
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_getCliente "+e_cliente.idCliente, cn);//lo que hace es Listarme todos los clientes con el id dado
          SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(dt);
          if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              e_cliente.setRegistro(System.Array.ConvertAll(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray, x => x.ToString().Trim()));
          }
      }
  ```
- Este es Mi Clase BeanCliente

  ```
  #region propiedades
  public int idCliente { get; set; }
  public string Nombres { get; set; }
  public string Apellidos { get; set; }
  public string Dni { get; set; }
  public string Contraseña { get; set; }
  public string Genero { get; set; }
  public string FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
  public string Direccion { get; set; }
  public int IdDistrito { get; set; }
  public string Correo { get; set; }
  public bool Eliminado { get; set; }
  public bool valido { get; set; }
  #endregion

  #region Metodos
  public void setRegistro(string [] aRegistro) {
      valido = aRegistro != null;
      if (valido)
      {
          idCliente = int.Parse(aRegistro[0]);
          Nombres = aRegistro[1];
          Apellidos = aRegistro[2];
          Dni = aRegistro[3];
          Contraseña = aRegistro[4];
          Genero = aRegistro[5];
          FechaNacimiento = aRegistro[6];
          Direccion = aRegistro[7];
          IdDistrito = int.Parse(aRegistro[8]);
          Correo = aRegistro[9];
          Eliminado = aRegistro[10] == "true";
      }
  }
  public object[] getRegistro()
  {
      return new object[] { idCliente, Nombres, Apellidos, Dni, Contraseña, Genero, FechaNacimiento, Direccion, IdDistrito, Correo, Eliminado };
  }
  ```

  -Tengo nociones de como hacerlo pero me resulta error agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: La entidad BeanCliente podrias crearlo en java mismo, con los mismos tipos de variables, los getters y setters se crean facilmente mediante clicks en eclipse.

Comment: eso si es sencillo...me refiero al convertall..en el dao

Comment: ¿Qué error te resulta?

Comment: @Jcastillo agrega información de tu datasource, quiero pensar que es una BDD SQLServer, pero no das más indicios